# Перестал работать рабочий проект на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется полностью рабочий проект (2 месяца назад всё работало, с того момента в нем ничего не менялось), который я всегда разворачивал в Docker-е. Скопировал сейчас свой репозиторий с GitHub, собрал контейнеры, выполнил `composer install` (пишу на всякий случай, чтобы не было ответов аля "Да ты, наверное, не выполнил команду `composer install` "). Выполняю миграции через artisan - вылетает ошибка 255, пишу просто `artisan` - ошибка 255, пробую зайти на сайт - ошибка 500. Облазил весь гугл, но решения найти так и не смог. Если сменить версию php c 7.4 (на которой до этого все работало) на 8+, то сайт начинает хотя бы открываться, но Artisan команды все так же не выполняются и выбрасывают ошибку 255, без какой-либо дополнительной информации. В чем может быть проблема?

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.10",
    "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "intervention/image": "^2.6",
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^5.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
    "laravel/passport": "^10.1",
    "laravel/socialite": "^5.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.3",
    "socialiteproviders/vkontakte": "^4.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/YukiDub/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

laravel.log (ничего интересного в нем не вижу, надо просто выполнить миграцию, но выполнить её я не могу из-за 255 ошибки в Artisan)

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'YukiDubDB.jobs' doesn't exist at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:368)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(368): PDO->prepare('select * from `...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(705): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('select * from `...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(672): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(376): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2385): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, false)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2373): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2907): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2374): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php(294): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(242): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->first()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(220): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->getNextAvailableJob('default')
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(29): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(223): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->transaction(Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(345): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->pop('default')
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(354): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}('default')
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(159): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->getNextJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue), 'default')
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(117): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(298): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1015): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(299): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#32 {main}
"}
```

Ошибки при выполнении artisan команд в логи php не попадают.

Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/YukiDub/YukiDubWeb

UPD. На Linux всё ещё смешнее, после выполнения любой Artisan команды я получаю тишину (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lxb-rGgxBZnVWL4VdFLF6vKvP1fGqXqX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Нам остаётся только гадать ибо вы не предоставили ни логов, ни текста ошибки, ни конфигурации вашего сервера.

Comment: Все крутится в docker-е, по этой причине конфигурацию и не предоставлял, она же никак не менялась. Стоят php-fmp 7.4 со всеми требуемыми для работы Laravel расширениями(pdo, и т.д), mysql 5.7.29 и Nginx. В вопрос добавил ссылку на репу, конфиг php хранятся по пути /php/php.ini-development

Comment: текста у ошибки нет, пишет error 255 и всё.

Comment: Удалите composer.lock и vendor директорию, и запустите composer install заново.

Comment: И такое я тоже пробовал - не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что ваш каталог `storage/ & bootstrap/cache` доступен для записи.

Убедитесь, что ваш файл .env не содержит пробелов.
Пример: `key=value istead of key=va lue`

Удалите `bootstrap/cache/config.php` файл. Затем выполните поочередно

```
composer dumpautoload
composer update
```

Попробуйте удалить `/bootstrap/compiled.php` ( если он у вас есть )

Comment: Такое решение я уже находил на просторах гугла, не помогло

Comment: config.php, кстати, не создается в кэше.